# OpenMP questions regarding tasks and nowait

Tags: multithreading, task, openmp

Can anyone tell me the answers to these questions? I think the answer for question b) is that the program on the left schedules task beta() and immediately executes alpha() on the same thread, while the program on the right simply schedules beta() and alpha() for execution by other threads. (please correct me if I'm wrong) [image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your homework. So, I will not tell you the solution, but I give a hint. To answer a) consider all implied barriers.

Comment: is it because then that single thread can schedule the tasks and then the other ones can immediately start executing them?

Comment: No. The task is started regardless of the `nowait` clause. Think about implied barriers. Were are implied barriers in this code? What exactly `nowait` clause do?

Comment: as far as I know, the only implicit barriers are after `#pragma omp parallel` and `#pragma omp single`. `nowait` here just seems strange to me since it's refering to code meant to be executed by a single thread that is only scheduling tasks and there's nothing else to be done besides the tasks themselves.

Comment: Yes, you are correct there are 2 implied barriers without `nowait`. Is both necessary?

Comment: if not having `nowait` doesn't prevent the tasks from starting I don't see what else is there to do in this case

Comment: OK. You are right the program works fine in both cases. The question is related to that if you know that there is an implied barrier at the end of single region. Since there is an another implied barrier just after that, this barrier is not necessary, so it can be skipped. In this example it does not make much difference, but it is easy to find an example when it improves the performance.

Comment: So I guess it's a poorly written question, due to the bad example, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234309/discussion-between-136-and-laci).

Comment: No, it is not a bad example. ok, let' continue in chat